# Is it possible to access these directories?

Tags: files, symlink

I'm trying to recover data from my Ready NasDuo which is Spark based with a 16kb block size. I've followed another post and successfully mounted the drive using a command like

```
sudo fuseext2 -o ro,allow_other /dev/sdb1 ~/mnt/external
```

However I can't access the directories that store my data. I can access some of the other directories though. Running `ls -l` gives me something like below. I'm trying to get into the directories highlighted in Red, for example media. If I try `cd media` I get a No Such File or Directory.

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `ls c`

Comment: Just because I need to say it: **don't write anything in `/` yourself, it's root's land over there**. It seems like you created symlinks right into `/` (even though they're dead know).

Comment: Your listing shows broken symlinks.  Try using df to show all mounted file systems (show the output of df). It may be the symlink is pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: I can't read your screenshot. Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 4):

The symlinks appearing in red indicates "broken" links - i.e. the target does not exist.

This seems to indicate that whatever was providing /c is not mounted.  You need to figure out the device that provides that data and mount it.

Comment: An `ls -al` will show where the symbolic link points  +1 as this is the correct answer...